# Amsterdam - How to reach from Schiphol Airport to Hotel Nes by cab and Metro?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, amsterdam, taxis, ams

I'm going to Amsterdam for the first time. I want to know how to reach [Hotel Nes](http://g.co/maps/w8hc4) from Schiphol airport.

I want to know about both options - **Metro** and **private taxi** and price for both. I heard that Metro is cheap but taxi is safer.

Are both options available 24 hours a day?

Address of Hotel Nes is `Kloveniersburgwal 137- 139, 1011 KE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Via Train

   - Train/Metro/Tram are only available from 6am until half past 12 the next day (00.30)
   - Schipol to Amsterdam will cost you around 4.30 Euro by train. You will alight at Centraal Station. After that you can walk. If you don't want to walk use tram which cost you 2.60 Euro.
   - Suggested route:

     From Schipol, use InterCity train towards Amsterdam Centraal (around 18 mins)

     From Amsterdam Central, walk to Centraal Station (2 mins)

     From Central Station, use tram no 9 to Diemen (8 mins, 4 stops) alight in Rembrandtplein

     Walk to Kloveniersburgwal 137, Binnenstad, The Netherlands(3 mins)
     [image]
2. Taxi

   - Like other cities, taxi is 24 hrs available in amsterdam.
   - Estimated fare during the office hours is around 39.33 Euro. (7.50 Euro for the first 2km and 2.20 Euro perkilometer after that)
   - Estimated time needed to reach destination : 25 minutes.

Comment: How much will take to reach to Hotel from Airport by cab ?

Comment: Depends on your arrival time. 39.33 Euro during the day. After office hours usually has extra.

Comment: Sorry I was asking about time

Comment: around 25 minutes.

Comment: Train from Schiphol to Amsterdam is 24h service (but from say 1am to 6am once per hour, at the edges of that timeframe once every half hour). Trams / bus / metro have no service in that rough timeframe. Definitely the cheapest option. Also note that only Schiphol taxis are allowed pickup at the airport.

Comment: You can combine the (night) train with a taxi from Centraal station, or use a night bus (not round the night and maybe not every night) if you think a taxi is a bit expensive. Safety is not a problem with any of the transport options.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [train from Schiphol to Amsterdam Centraal Station](http://www.amsterdam.info/airport/train/). As far as I can remember it is easy to find.

From Centraal Station, this is 1.3 km by foot or 17 mn, [according to google maps](http://maps.google.co.in/maps?saddr=centraal&daddr=Kloveniersburgwal%20137-%20139,%201011%20KE%20Amsterdam,%20Netherlands%20%28Hotel%20Nes%29&hl=en&ll=52.373975,4.899173&spn=0.020043,0.055575&sll=52.373058,4.898701&sspn=0.020043,0.055575&geocode=FWU6HwMd6MVKACEjaQCoXcIdayk57nJztwnGRzFrWhNBAKMjpw;FU0SHwMdH7ZKACF7_5yMzQnN9inHi8zqvwnGRzHf6Vk-HMMAKw&gl=in&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&t=m&z=15) (a search using public transportation is available as well on that page).

Comment: Trainstation is directly underneath the main hall (public part) at Schiphol airport. There are huge signs….

Answer (score 2):

Live journey plans are available at https://9292.nl/en There is also a 9292 mobile app which is well worth putting on your phone if you are visiting Amsterdam. The best journey will depend on the time of day, and live public transport conditions, so use the app.

For an indication of the journey in the question here's the link: https://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/station-schiphol-airport/amsterdam_kloveniersburgwal-137/

Taxis in Amsterdam are expensive.

Comment: Hi - are you affiliated with the mobile app and site you mention?

Comment: No - I happen to live in Amsterdam, and that's what people use. AFAIK it's something to do with the public transport service.